# Grails - detect if request is over HTTP or HTTPS

Tags: grails, https, request

In Grails how do you ask if the request coming in is http or https?
Should you approach this from the request object?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `request.isSecure()`. This isn't a Grails feature btw, it's in the `javax.servlet.ServletRequest` interface.

Comment: Very cool simple way to toggle between https and http. Thanks. +1 and answer

Comment: `request.isSecure()` also checks the `X-Forwarded-Proto` [header field](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/x-forwarded-headers.html#x-forwarded-proto), so it even works behind an SSL terminating load balancer (where your Grails instance is actually on HTTP:80).